# Matching words with spaces regex in java

Tags: java, regex

This one is so simple, but seems to be stumping me.

I have the following text line:

```
for        months to
```

I am trying to match it with the following regex:

```
for\s*months\s*to
```

I read this regex as:

1. Must have the word "for"
2. Followed by any amount of space
3. Followed by the word "months"
4. Followed by any amount of space
5. Followed by the word "to"

And to me, this should match, but it doesnt. Can anyone see where I might have gone wrong.

Comment: You probably have extra white spaces (and copying your code there are extra white spaces after 'to'). Here is a link that should help you out. http://fiddle.re/26pu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most likely have preceding or succeeding whitespace. Using `String.matches(String regex)` you must match the *entire* string.

Try `"\\s*for\\s+months\\s+to\\s*"`

Comment: I changed it to this: `\s*for\s*months\s*to` to allow for any white space t the begining, but it still doesnt match

Comment: that's because you have extra whitespace at the end in the example you have above.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the trailing spaces.

Try this:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("for\\s*months\\s*to\\s*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("for        months to   ");
    System.out.println(m.matches());
```

Comment: after your answer I selected the "following text line" from OPs question and the selection revealed trailing whitespace. good catch! :)